# Beaglebone black + Weather Cape

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a program that I need to use beaglebone black and weather cape to get the sensor value. However, I only managed to get the sensor value in raw data with my beaglebone attached to it. The problem now is that I need to convert the raw data into percentage/Celsius but It work only when I try the codes in bonescript. I need to retrieve those data from the bonescript and store in my Linux application which after that store the value in a database using MySQL. Does anybody know the code or got any solution?

Any kind souls? Deeply appreciated!

Regards,
Tiffany

Comment: Please share what code you've got so far and what's wrong with it. Makes it easier for someone to adapt or extend it.

Comment: I try to add the code but they don't allow me.

Comment: var b = require('bonescript');
//var fs = require('fs'); // needed to open files
var iic = '/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/'; 

// Sensor Locations on the BeagleBone Black
var pressureInput = '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/pressure0_input';
var humidityInput = '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0040/humidity1_input';
var temperatureInput0= '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0077/temp0_input';
var luxInput= '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0039/lux1_input';
var temperatureInput1= '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/1-0040/temp1_input;

Comment: //We will initialize the driver for the BMP085 sensor located at I2C location 0x77
b.writeTextFile(iic + 'new_device', 'bmp085 0x77');

// Location where the sensor values are placed in a .txt file
//var out = fs.createWriteStream('/home/root/Desktop/sensors.txt', {flags: 'w'}); // the location we will write the inputs
//console.log("The following values have been read by the WeatherCape:\n");
//out.write("The following values have been read by the Weather Cape:\n");

Comment: /* Opens,reads, and prints humidity, lux, pressure, and temperature. */
b.readTextFile(pressureInput, printPressure);
b.readTextFile(humidityInput, printHumidity);
b.readTextFile(temperatureInput0, printTemperature);
b.readTextFile(luxInput, printLux);

/* Prints Pressure */
function printPressure(x) {
   console.log("Pressure: ", x.data/100 + " millibar");
   out.write("\tPressure is: " + x.data/100 + " millibar\n");
}

Comment: /* Prints Humidity */
function printHumidity(x){
   console.log(x.data/1000+ "% Humidity");
   out.write('\t' + x.data/1000 + "% Humidity\n");
}

Comment: /* Prints Temperature */
function printTemperature(x){
   console.log("Temperature: ", x.data/10 + '\xB0' + " Celcius"); // '\xB0' is decimal in hexademical
   out.write("\tTemperature is: " + x.data/10 + " degrees Celcius\n");
   x.data /= 10;
   x.data *= 1.8;
   x.data += 32;
   console.log("or: ", parseFloat(x.data).toFixed(3) + '\xB0' + " Fahrenheit");
   out.write("\t\t    or: " + x.data + " degrees" + " Fahrenheit\n");
   out.write("*********************************************************\n");
}

Comment: /* Prints Lux */
function printLux(x){
   console.log("Lux: ", x.data);
    out.write("\tLux: " + x.data);
}
out.write("*********************************************************\n");